# Lazy Sequence Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I was trying to modify a vector of vector but ended up with lazy-seq inside. I am new to clojure. Can someone help me to get this correctly?

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

;;READ CUST.TXT
(def my_str(slurp "cust.txt"))
(defn esplit [x] (str/split x #"\|" ))
(def cust (vec (sort-by first (vec (map esplit (vec (str/split my_str #"\n")))))))
;;func to print
(for [i cust] (do (println (str (subs (str i) 2 3) ": [" (subs (str i) 5 (count (str i)))))))


;;CODE TO SEARCH CUST
(defn cust_find [x] (for [i cust :when (= (first i) x )] (do (nth i 1))))
(type (cust_find "2"))

;;READ PROD.TXT
(def my_str(slurp "prod.txt"))
(def prod (vec (sort-by first (vec (map esplit (vec (str/split my_str #"\n")))))))
;;func to print
(for [i prod] (do (println (str (subs (str i) 2 3) ": [" (subs (str i) 5 (count (str i)))))))

;;CODE TO SEARCH PROD
(defn prod_find [x y] (for [i prod :when (= (first i) x )] (nth i y)))
(prod_find "2" 1)

(def my_str(slurp "sales.txt"))
(def sales (vec (sort-by first (vec (map esplit (vec (str/split my_str #"\n")))))))
; (for [i (range(count sales))] (cust_find (nth (nth sales i) 1)))
; (defn fill_sales_1 [x]
;   (assoc x 1
;     (cust_find (nth x 1))))
; (def sales(map fill_sales_1 (sales)))
(def sales (vec (for [i (range(count sales))]  (assoc (nth sales i) 1 (str (cust_find (nth (nth sales i) 1)))))))
; (for [i (range(count sales))] (assoc (nth sales i) 2 (str (prod_find (nth (nth sales i) 2) 1))))
(for [i sales] (println i))
```

When I print sales vector I get

```
[1 clojure.lang.LazySeq@10ae5ccd 1 3]
[2 clojure.lang.LazySeq@a5d0ddf9 2 3]
[3 clojure.lang.LazySeq@a5d0ddf9 1 1]
[4 clojure.lang.LazySeq@d80cb028 3 4]
```

If you need the text files I will upload them as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Clojure, `for` and `map`, as well as other functions and macros working with sequences, generate a lazy sequence instead of a vector.

In the REPL, lazy sequences are usually fully computed when printing - to have it printed, it's enough to remove the `str` in your second to last line:

```
(def sales (vec (for [i (range(count sales))]  (assoc (nth sales i) 1 (cust_find (nth (nth sales i) 1))))))
```

Just in case, note that your code can be prettified / simplified to convey the meaning better. For example, you are just iterating over a sequence of `sales` - you don't need to iterate over the indices and then get each item using `nth`:

```
(def sales
  (vec (for [rec sales])
         (assoc rec 1 (cust_find (nth rec 1)))))
```

Second, you can replace `nth ... 1` with `second` - it will be easier to understand:

```
(def sales
  (vec (for [rec sales])
         (assoc rec 1 (cust_find (second rec))))
```

Or, alternatively, you can just use `update` instead of `assoc`:

```
(def sales
  (vec (for [rec sales])
         (update rec 1 cust_find)))
```

And, do you really need the outer `vec` here? You can do most of what you intend without it:

```
(def sales
  (for [rec sales])
    (update rec 1 cust_find))
```

Also, using underscores in Clojure function names is considered [bad style](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#lisp-case): dashes (as in `cust-find` instead of `cust_find`) are easier to read and easier to type.

Answer (score -1):

`(for [i sales] (println (doall i)))`

[doall](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) realizes a lazy sequence. Bare in mind that if the sequence is huge, you might not want to do this.